# Lumen, How to load a file that is out of the project

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a pdf file inside the documents folder of my user, which I need to return through a route.
For this I wrote the following simple function

```
public function showPdf(){
    return response()->file('/home/victor/Documents/1-39-1.pdf');
}
```

But when I call this function through a GET, the browser returns the following exception

> Method Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory::file does not exist.

How can I tell lumen that my file is on that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lumen 7.x this method is named download and can be seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/6f599287fc1f689c0ec8dc0c15ba9180f5bb7c72/src/Http/ResponseFactory.php#L65). This is fairly similar to Laravels `file()`, therefor this change should work.

```
return response()->download('/home/victor/Documents/1-39-1.pdf');
```